# XML Serialization: is Order mandatory on your class when you specifiy at least 1 Order attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Using the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class OrderedClass
{
    private int field1;
    private string field2;
    private string field3;

    [XmlElement(Order = 30)]
    public string Field3
    {
        get { return field3; }
        set { field3 = value; }
    }

    public int Field1
    {
        get { return field1; }
        set { field1 = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(Order = 20)]
    public string Field2
    {
        get { return field2; }
        set { field2 = value; }
    }

    public OrderedClass()
    {
        field1 = 1;
        field2 = "String1";
        field3 = "String2";
    }
}`
```

Would this serialize without setting an order on `public int Field1` ?
I thought this would behind the scenes set its order to 0, but instead I'm getting a reflection error when trying to serialize with 
`XmlSerializer orderedSerializer =
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedClass));`

Comment: How do you serialize(your code)? What exception do you get(message,stack trace)?

Comment: I serialize the class using `XmlSerializer orderedSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedClass));`

The error is: There was an error reflecting type 'GeneralTestApp.OrderedClass'.

And inner exception: {"Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the 'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray custom attribute on class member 'Field1'."}

Comment: StevenVL, see the InnerException, It should give more detailed info.

Comment: Might it be that I'm confusing the ruleset about XmlElements with DataMembers?

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, the difference was indeed between XmlElement order, and DataMember order. When defining an Order on XmlEments, you need all XmlElements to have an order.

When defining order on DataMembers the following rules apply:

- If a data contract type is a part of an inheritance hierarchy, data members of its base types are always first in the order.
- Next in order are the current type’s data members that do not have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set, in alphabetical order.
- Next are any data members that have the Order property of the DataMemberAttribute attribute set. These are ordered by the value of the Order property first and then alphabetically if there is more than one member of a certain Order value. Order values may be skipped.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I got same serialization error

Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the 'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray custom attribute on class member 'Id'

The reason was that i extended the WSDL based proxy class using the partial pattern, and forgot to set [XmlIgnore] on the virtual properties i added:

```
public partical class MyWsdlProxyClass
{
   [XmlIgnore]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

The XmlIgnore flag in above code saved me, because this property was actually not part of the serialized XML.